# When generating a PDF with Flying Saucer the header overlaps with the body

Tags: java, flying-saucer

I am using Flying Saucer R8 to generate PDF files. The PDFs need a header which is going to be repeated on every page. The header is going to be specified by the user so I am unable to determine it's height. I managed to make the header repeat on every page but the problem is that if the header has more than one row of text, it does not dynamically readjust the height of the body and it ends up overlapping it. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@page {
    size: 4.18in 6.88in;
    margin: 0.25in;
    @top-center {content: element(header);}
}
#header {
    color: red;
    display: block;
    position: running(header);  
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <-- Lots of text here --> 
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <-- Lots of text here -->   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After generating with Flying Saucer the resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone please help me find a solution for my header not to overlap with the rest of the body?

Comment: Please add images directly to a question, rather than in a link.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't have the necessary reputation to add the image directly to the question.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else is having this problem I managed to find a workaround for it. To dynamically calculate the size of the header in your PDF forget about CSS running headers and instead make your whole page an HTML table and put your header in the `thead` section. Use the following CSS rule to make the `thead` repeat on each page:

```
table {
   -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone else is having the same problem, I found a different solution that worked for me.

Headers and footers are established within the page margins.
So the solution is to increase the page top margin, for example:

```
@page {
        margin-top: 50mm; 
}
```

This solution was copied from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31470840/1271573

Answer (score 1):

simply try adding margin/padding to your `<div class="section"></div>` via css. This should do the trick.

The header overlapps because it is not positioned as all the other elements on the page. It is a [running element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#running-elements) that is treated in a special way when in print mode. So you have to make sure, there is enough space if these elements occur anywhere on your page.

Comment: Adding a margin or padding to my div does not help because it is only calculated once (in the first page).